# GMail API user rate-limited over extended period of time

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to do a simple call to get the email address of an account:

```
gmail().users().getProfile("me").execute().getEmailAddress();
```

However it always returns a user-rate-limited response:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 429 unknown
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2019-09-18T18:49:00.748Z",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2019-09-18T18:49:00.748Z"
}
```

Regardless of waiting after the time mentioned, it always is returning this response. I had it retry for once an hour for the past 14 hours and it is still giving this response. I have checked my API quota and confirmed there is no other usage of the user for GMail in the timeframe.

I do have exponential backoff implemented, however due to an internal issue on my script yesterday there were many requests in a short period of time to the GMail API. As expected it hit the rate limit, but it appears that the rate limitation has not "turned off" since. Is this user-account blacklisted? How can I get the account up and running again?

Comment: It seems like the sending limits are bound to the whole account (that has sets of many email addresses/aliases) ?
Google is so confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota):

> Mail Sending Limits 
>   The Gmail API enforces the standard daily mail
>   sending limits.
>
> If these limits
>   are exceeded a HTTP 429 Too Many Requests **"User-rate limit exceeded"**
>   error mentioning "(Mail sending)" is returned with a time to retry.

The [email sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852)

> are applied over a rolling **24-hour** period.

This explains why you needed to wait 24 hours since the original issue.

Have a look at the [email sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852), so you know which quota you exceeded and need avoid it in the future.

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka

I stumbled upon this thread as I was looking for "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after <timestamp>" error from Gmail API.
In my case, I am using messages().get method.

Even in the original question, it was 'get' request.

So, I don't understand how email 'sending' limits will apply for a get request?

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: It specifies [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota): `usage limit that applies to ALL requests made from your application` and `Per User Rate Limit: 250 quota units per user per second` and `messages.get: 5 quota units`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I was focused on the 'per-user limits' section on that page, and it only mentions sending / bandwidth limits and concurrent req.

Also, the per-method quota usage section starts off by mentioning "Daily usage limit"
So, at least I find this page quite confusing.

Just to be sure I understood this right, I can make at most 5 message.get calls per second, and the 6th call will result in user-rate limit exceeded (for simplicity, keeping aside the moving avg allowing short bursts aspect)?

Comment: Should be more like 50 calls per second, but it depends on how they calculate the rate (per second? per minute? per 100 miliseconds?)? Basically - if you keep getting the error - decrease your request speed, e.g. with exponential backoff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is patience, or maybe it's luck. But now after roughly 24 hours since the original issue with the requests my account appears to be working again.